# Why do not extensions with a remote work area work?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have started using "VsCode" as a text editor for my projects in php. I usually work in remote servers so I need another application to download the files and edit them, like "Filezilla".

Today he discovered the extension "Ssh fs" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs) that what he does is create a work area with connection to the server and work directly on it, everything from "VsCode".

The truth is that it works very well.

The problem is that I have some extensions installed (like a code formatter, etc) and when I connect to the server they do not appear and I can not use them.

Comment: Various extensions points are registered with a schema, for example 'file'.   This is because the code assumes the I/O is done via a filesystem so it would not work with a non-filesystem based extension.

Comment: Then I'll have to find another way, thanks for the answer.